# Updating TabsetPanel won't work when put inside a module: R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app which creates and updates a tabsetPanel based on a checklist. This works fine.

### app.R

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Dynamic TabsetPanel"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput(
        "tabs",
        "Select Tabs",
        choices = c("Tab 1", "Tab 2", "Tab 3"),
        selected = "Tab 1"
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("myTabs")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$myTabs <- renderUI({
    tabs <- input$tabs

    # Dynamically generate tabsetPanel based on checkboxGroupInput
    do.call(
      tabsetPanel,
      lapply(
        tabs,
        function(tab) {
          tabPanel(tab, h3(paste("Content for", tab)))
        }
      )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I put it inside a module. Now, I have `mod_tabsetpanel.R` and `app.R`.
When I run `app.R`, the app opens, but no tabs are generated even when the checklist options are selected.

### mod_tabsetpanel.R

```
mod_tabsetpanel_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("dynamic_tabs"))
  )
}

mod_tabsetpanel_server <- function(id, tab_names) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$dynamic_tabs <- renderUI({
      # Create a list of tabPanel objects
      tabPanelsList <- lapply(tab_names, function(tab) {
        tabPanel(
          tab,
          h3(paste("Content for", tab))
        )
      })
      do.call(tabsetPanel, tabPanelsList)
    })
  })
}
```

### app.R

```
library(shiny)
source("mod_tabsetpanel.R")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Tabset"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput(
        inputId = "val",
        label = "Values",
        choices = c("Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      mod_tabsetpanel_ui("aaa"),
      fluidRow(
        textOutput("abc")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$abc <- renderText({input$val})
  mod_tabsetpanel_server("aaa", input$val)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

`input$val` works with `textOutput("abc")` and `output$abc`, so I know the input is being fed into the module. I'm not sure why the tabsetPanel isn't being created.

I've tried:
1.
In `app.R`:
`mod_tabsetpanel_server("aaa", input$val)` to `mod_tabsetpanel_server("aaa", input$val, parent = session)`
In `mod_tabsetpanel.R`:
`modtabsetpanel_server <- function(id, tab_names)` to `modtabsetpanel_server <- function(id, tab_names, parent)`
`moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session)` to `moduleServer(id, function(input, output, parent)`
2.
Wrapping everything in `moduleServer` in an `observe({})` call.

Everything yields the same result, app runs but no tab panels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule pass values which are supposed to be reactive, like `input`s, as `reactive`s to modules, i.e. wrap `input$value` in `reactive()`. In your server you then have to access the values using `()`, i.e. use `tab_names()`:

```r
mod_tabsetpanel_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("dynamic_tabs"))
  )
}

mod_tabsetpanel_server <- function(id, tab_names) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$dynamic_tabs <- renderUI({
      # Create a list of tabPanel objects
      tabPanelsList <- lapply(tab_names(), function(tab) {
        tabPanel(
          tab,
          h3(paste("Content for", tab))
        )
      })
      do.call(tabsetPanel, tabPanelsList)
    })
  })
}

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Tabset"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput(
        inputId = "val",
        label = "Values",
        choices = c("Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3"),
        selected = c("Tab1", "Tab2")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      mod_tabsetpanel_ui("aaa"),
      fluidRow(
        textOutput("abc")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$abc <- renderText({
    input$val
  })
  mod_tabsetpanel_server("aaa", reactive(input$val))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3792
```

[image]

Comment: ohhh ok, thank you! I assumed input$val was already reactive so that wasn't something I considered.